Help using the delta method
I am trying to calculate the variance for the ratio of two random variables using the Delta Method (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method) : $R = X/Y$.
I know that the Taylor Series are involved for this problem.
For a univariate function $f(x)$ expanded around point $a$:
$$f(x) = f(a) + f'(a)(x-a) + \frac{f''(a)}{2!}(x-a)^2 + \frac{f'''(a)}{3!}(x-a)^3 + \cdots$$
For a multivariate function $f(\mathbf{x})$ expanded around point $\mathbf{a}$ ($\nabla f$ is a vector of first partial derivatives, $\mathbf{H}$ is a matrix of second partial derivatives):
$$f(\mathbf{x}) = f(\mathbf{a}) + \nabla f(\mathbf{a}) \cdot (\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{a}) + \frac{1}{2!}(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{a})^T \mathbf{H}(\mathbf{a}) (\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{a}) + ....$$
Suppose I decide to evaluate the Taylor Series of the ratio around $(\mu_X, \mu_Y)$:
$$\frac{X}{Y} \approx \frac{\mu_X}{\mu_Y} + \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial}{\partial X}(\frac{X}{Y}) & \frac{\partial}{\partial Y}(\frac{X}{Y}) \end{bmatrix}_{\big|_{(\mu_X,\mu_Y)}} \begin{bmatrix} X-\mu_X \\ Y-\mu_Y \end{bmatrix}$$
The first two partial derivatives:
For $\frac{\partial}{\partial X}(\frac{X}{Y})$:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial X}(\frac{X}{Y}) = \frac{1}{Y}$$
For $\frac{\partial}{\partial Y}(\frac{X}{Y})$:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial Y}(\frac{X}{Y}) = X \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial Y}(\frac{1}{Y}) = X \cdot (-\frac{1}{Y^2}) = -\frac{X}{Y^2}$$
This now becomes:
$$\frac{X}{Y} \approx \frac{\mu_X}{\mu_Y} + \frac{1}{\mu_Y}(X-\mu_X) - \frac{\mu_X}{\mu_Y^2}(Y-\mu_Y)$$
Now, to find the variance, we use the classic formula $Z$: $\text{Var}(Z) = E[(Z-E[Z])^2]$
$$\frac{X}{Y} \approx \frac{\mu_X}{\mu_Y} + \frac{1}{\mu_Y}(X-\mu_X) - \frac{\mu_X}{\mu_Y^2}(Y-\mu_Y)$$
$$\text{Var}(\frac{X}{Y}) \approx \text{Var}\left(\frac{1}{\mu_Y}(X-\mu_X) - \frac{\mu_X}{\mu_Y^2}(Y-\mu_Y)\right)$$
Using the variance of a sum formula: $$\text{Var}(aU + bV) = a^2\text{Var}(U) + b^2\text{Var}(V) + 2ab\text{Cov}(U,V)$$
Here:

$a = \frac{1}{\mu_Y}$
$b = -\frac{\mu_X}{\mu_Y^2}$
$U = (X-\mu_X)$
$V = (Y-\mu_Y)$

Then:
$$\text{Var}(\frac{X}{Y}) \approx (\frac{1}{\mu_Y})^2\text{Var}(X-\mu_X) + (-\frac{\mu_X}{\mu_Y^2})^2\text{Var}(Y-\mu_Y) + 2(\frac{1}{\mu_Y})(-\frac{\mu_X}{\mu_Y^2})\text{Cov}(X-\mu_X,Y-\mu_Y)$$
By definition:

$\text{Var}(X-\mu_X) = \text{Var}(X)$
$\text{Var}(Y-\mu_Y) = \text{Var}(Y)$
$\text{Cov}(X-\mu_X,Y-\mu_Y) = \text{Cov}(X,Y)$

Thus, the final answer becomes:
$$\text{Var}(\frac{X}{Y}) \approx \frac{\text{Var}(X)}{\mu_Y^2} + \frac{\mu_X^2\text{Var}(Y)}{\mu_Y^4} - \frac{2\mu_X\text{Cov}(X,Y)}{\mu_Y^3}$$
Is my work correct?


Footnote 1: Adapting this formula to find the variance around an arbitrary point $(x_1, y_1)$ instead of $(\mu_X, \mu_Y)$. (I read the Delta method is more accurate around the mean values)

Starting with the Taylor expansion around $(x_1, y_1)$:
$$\frac{X}{Y} \approx \frac{x_1}{y_1} + \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{y_1} & -\frac{x_1}{y_1^2} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} X-x_1 \\ Y-y_1 \end{bmatrix}$$
$$\frac{X}{Y} \approx \frac{x_1}{y_1} + \frac{1}{y_1}(X-x_1) - \frac{x_1}{y_1^2}(Y-y_1)$$
Variance calculation process as before:
$$\text{Var}(\frac{X}{Y}) \approx \text{Var}\left(\frac{1}{y_1}(X-x_1) - \frac{x_1}{y_1^2}(Y-y_1)\right)$$
$$\text{Var}(\frac{X}{Y}) \approx \frac{\text{Var}(X)}{y_1^2} + \frac{x_1^2\text{Var}(Y)}{y_1^4} - \frac{2x_1\text{Cov}(X,Y)}{y_1^3}$$


Footnote 2:  Why $\text{Var}(X-x_1) = \text{Var}(X)$

For any random variable $X$ and any constant $c$,the fundamental property of variance:
$$\text{Var}(X \pm c) = \text{Var}(X)$$
$$\text{Var}(X-c) = E[(X-c-E[X-c])^2]$$
$$= E[(X-c-(E[X]-c))^2]$$
$$= E[(X-E[X])^2]$$
$$= \text{Var}(X)$$
Thus:
$$\text{Var}(X-x_1) = \text{Var}(X)$$
$$\text{Var}(X-\mu_X) = \text{Var}(X)$$
